# Encontrar String em ArrayList

Tags: java, array, string, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> posicoes = new ArrayList<String>();

posicoes.add("Ricardo;01051509912;gmail");
posicoes.add("Renato;123456789123;hotmail");
posicoes.add("Rodrigo;09873923121;yahoo");
```

Tenho uma `ArrayList` cujo nome é `posicoes` e preciso fazer uma busca nela que me retorne a posição (índice) da `String`.

Por exemplo:

```
Localizar: 01051509912 // Retorno: posicoes[0]
Localizar: 123456789123 // Retorno: posicoes[1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem que varrer a lista toda. Pode fazer de várias formas, a mais básica é com um `for`. E em cada item deve verificar se [a *string* contém a outra *string*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) que está buscando.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
            ArrayList<String> posicoes = new ArrayList<String>();
            posicoes.add("Ricardo;01051509912;gmail");
            posicoes.add("Renato;123456789123;hotmail");
            posicoes.add("Rodrigo;09873923121;yahoo");
            System.out.println(BuscaString(posicoes, "01051509912"));
            System.out.println(BuscaString(posicoes, "123456789123"));
    }
    public static int BuscaString(ArrayList<String> lista, String busca) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) if (lista.get(i).contains(busca)) return i;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TQnnEd). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/frrhuhuz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/FindString.java).

[Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Usei `-1` para indicar que não achou o que deseja.